# Necesito obtener promedio del resultado obtenido de la query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
tbl.cod_afp,tbl.glosa,tiempo_promedio_seg=AVG(tbl.tiempo_trx_seg)
FROM  #tbl_detalle_trx_AFP AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.cod_afp,tbl.glosa
ORDER BY tbl.cod_afp,tbl.glosa
```

Comment: Y cuál el el error?

Comment: El resultado de esa query tira muchas cosas. 3 columnas, para ser más específico.
Querés obtener el promedio del resultado de las 3 columnas? Ayudanos a ayudarte, sé un poco más específica en lo que necesitás.

Comment: Hola Federico, necesito promedio del resultado de la última columna, que contiene los promedios individuales, pero necesito el promedio total general. Por ejemplo                        1 Privado 0.0009245
2 Pregrado 0.005706
3 Universitario 0.000901
4 Prueba 0.000151
Promedio Total  ??

Comment: @maria para poder recibir una buena respuesta, debes de plantear bien tu pregunta, dar detalles de la misma, lo que has intentado, en que estás atorada, etc. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar los detalles correspondientes y así poder recibir una respuesta adecuada.